# php regex to split invoice line item description

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am attempting to split strings like the following:

An item (`Item A`) which may contain 89798 numbers and letters @ $550.00

4 of `Item B` @ $420.00

476584 of `Item C`, with a larger quantity and different currency symbol @ £420.00

into:

```
array(

    0 => 1

    1 => "some item which may contain 89798 numbers and letters"

    2 => $550.00

);
```

does that make sense?

I am looking for a regex pattern which will split the quantity, description, and price (including symbol).

the strings will always be:

`qty x description @ price+symbol`

so i assume the regex would be something like:

```
`(match a number and only a number) x (get description letters and numbers before the @ symbol) @ (match the currency symbol and price)`
```

How should I approach this?

Comment: In two of your examples, there is not a space to the left of the `x`.  Is this how string really is, or is this a typo and you are guaranteed spaces around both the `x` and the `@`?

Comment: sorry, yes it is always going to have a space either side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^(\d+)\s*x\s(.+)\s@\s*([^@]+)$/', $string, $match);
unset($match[0]);
print_r($match);
```

Comment: Would it be better to make the final check `@\s*([^@]+)$`, or something similar? Just in case there's a product that has an `@` in the name?

Comment: this is perfect, and works well even when the description contains @ symbols, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If there will always be  whitespace around either side of `x` and `@` You can try this:

```
$pattern = '/\s*(x|@)\s*/';
$array = preg_split($pattern, $input_string);
```

Comment: love the simplicity, and performance over the above answer, but it breaks if the description contains @ symbols. thanks anyway